# Cannot open app from widget. (using URL)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, today-extension

I'm trying to launch my app when the user tap my widget.

Here's my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let myAppUrl = NSURL(string: "Sleep-Analysis")!
    extensionContext?.open(myAppUrl as URL, completionHandler: { (success) in
        if (!success) {
           print("error")            }
    })
}
```

But the app doesn't launch but gave me this error.

```
2017-01-13 09:36:23.921768 Sleep Timer Widget[10365:3109526] __55-[_NCWidgetExtensionContext openURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke failed: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"
```

I have already set up the URL scheme in both the info.plist and the info section of the project.

I may have done something wrong but here's the screenshot of the info.plist

[image]

This is my project info section.

[image]

Comment: Did you find the problem? I am currently having the exact same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

I think the `URL` string format is not correct.

Try this:

```
extensionContext?.open(URL(string: "Sleep-Analysis://")!, completionHandler: { (success) in
            if (!success)
            {
                print("error")
            }
        })
```